# Python reload issue in interpereter mode

Tags: python

```
  # python
  enter code herePython 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
  [GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
  >>> import os,sys
  >>> import setup
  ..........
  ..........
  ..........
 >>> reload(setup)
 <module 'setup' from 'setup.pyc'>
 >>>
```

But after executing reload its not taking updated 'setup' module

For example:
Doing some change in 'setup' file in another session and reloading in interpreter mode. But unable to use updated 'setup'

Could any will help me, how to overcome from this issue or where i am doing wrong

Thanks in Advance
Abhishek

Answer (score 3):

`reload` reloads a module, but doesn't recompile it.

```
>>> reload(setup)
<module 'setup' from 'setup.pyc'>
```

It is reloading from the compiled `setup.pyc`, not `setup.py`.  The easiest way to get around this is simply to delete `setup.pyc` after making changes.  Then when it reloads `setup.py` it will first recompile it.

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the value returned by `reload` to the same variable:

```
setup = reload(setup)
```